# What features can I add to this FIDE chess application? (edits made 2/25)

Tags: analysis, statistics, fide, programming

**EDIT: Most of the app is completed. Now all I have to complete is implementation of FIDE arbiters, a dynamic 3d plot (right now it only has 3 variables being plotted, no inputs affect it), adding more FIDE data (based on months) and perhaps including USCF chess data (I have the latest data set for all of the states).**

**I have made 3 adjustments to this post.**

**1.Include a dynamic time series chart that lets you see more than one player at a time: This was very time consuming to produce!.**

**2.Include an overlayed histogram/density curve.**

**3.Include 3d scatterplot**

**4.Improve the layout of the app**

---

#### FIDE CHESS APPLICATION

Other than an interactive chess board itself (which would be a different animal in itself), what can I add to this application to improve upon visualizing and summarizing aggregated FIDE chess statistics? I am planning also to add a time series plot and a motion chart for aggregated historical data.

After I have completed it, I will put up the source code onto github/mediafire for those who are interested in the programming aspect of this. I will also eventually find a place to host this application so that you may use at your leisure.

---

Here is a picture of the application itself. The left side has filters that effect the output on the right side.

[image]

---

Here are a few images of features I have put in it.

#### Key for graphs below:

1. The first graph is an interactive map that outputs the number of FIDE rated players for each country and plots it onto a map.
2. The second graph is a normalized histogram, or density curve describing the FIDE ratings distribution.
3. Similiar to the map, this is a barplot of the number players in each country
4. The globe is the map, but a more appealing version of the map.
5. Ideally, I will be able to include a 2D/3D time series plot, unsure if it will be possible given how the datasets are structured. I would plot aggregated chess statistics of the FIDE chess population or of individual players here.
6. A google motion chart, similar to a time series plot, but more interactive and visually appealing. As with the time series plot, I would plot aggregated chess statistics of the FIDE chess population or of individual players here.
7. Scatterplot of 3 variables

---

[image: Number of players described onto a map]

[image]

[image: Bar plot of the number of players]

[image: Number if players described onto a globe]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Is there anything else I can add to further visual FIDE chess data? Also,  making suggestions to further improve upon what I have would be good too.**

Comment: Stats on the number of Tournaments organized by each federation for different years ?  That would also be cool.

Comment: Where I can find this application? I want to try it.

Comment: @ArunJ, I don't have access to tournament director information. Unless FIDE provides a specific dataset for that, I don't have a choice, but to datascrape the website. That will not happen anytime soon.

Comment: @StudentT, This is not available at the moment. Once I am done with this (not sure about the time table), I will attempt to get it hosted on a few websites so that anyone may use it.

Comment: Good luck with your visualisation! I think the R graphics look great!

Comment: @Bad_Bishop and people who want to conduct analysis on this data /

While the R-graphics are great, if you ever want to import text data files that are poorly formatted like the ones on the FIDE main website, make sure NOT to use R initially to do so! R can not interpret FIDE's formatted text files.

I advise you to use SAS, if possible, to separate the values into particular columns using a fixed input statement within the data step when you import the set.

While this isn't a problem for one data set, i want to do time series and motion charts: which require all 96, 97 sets provided by FIDE.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Do you have a website or a Twitter account that I can follow. I want to be notified when you're ready to publish.

Comment: I'm working with a friend of mine to acquire a domain on some website in order to get it up and running. I have never used twitter, but if you'd like to be informed, follow me on YouTube (same username), Ive posted a video there detailing what I had done through about 5 days back. Also, adding me as a friend on chess.com/lichess (username: Infiniteflash) would be a good idea as well. I will post a new thread about the final product after I have it published.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, good luck! It looks like a really interesting project.

As to suggestions:

1) What are you thinking of calling the app? From what you have shown here, maybe "FIDE Player Statistics"?

2) What is the situation regarding ownership and copyright of the data? Maybe you should ask FIDE? There again, as far as I know they don't make the underlying data publicly available so you have to "mine" the data via appropriately constructed web requests. In this case I don't think you would need permission.

3) You could add displays for player titles like GM, IM, FM, CM, WGM, WIM, etc.

4) You could include arbiter information - IA, FA

5) Also trainers and international organizers.

6) For all of your statistics to break out the data in federation terms. This is almost country level but some countries have a privileged situation. For instance the UK actually has separate English, Scottish, Welsh federations, etc. So, allow comparison of titled players per federation, titled players per thousand players per federation. Could be fascinating to see how Russia performs here. Is it still number 1 chess country / federation?

7) Same for arbiters.

8) Same for organizers.

9) Same for trainers.

I will be very interested in the results of this project. It looks fascinating. Please keep us informed!

Comment: 1. I am unsure of what to call it when its finally done. For now its just visualizing chess data.

2. The data is provided for free on the fide chess website in a text file format.  Here's the link: http://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml

3. Yes, i will include this soon.

4/5. I don't have access to this data.

6/7/8/9. I will look at finding data for each country's federation, but this seems to be unreasonable for me to do anytime soon. At this time, I am primarily focused on the FIDE chess datasets provided at that link.

Thanks, and will do.

Comment: If it helps, FIDE has a pdf with a list of licensed arbiters: http://arbiters.fide.com/licensed-arbiters.html

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess "4/5. I don't have access to this data. " Yes, you do! (Thanks for the link). I downloaded the zipped xml file and searched for Adam Raoof, who I know is both an IA and IO. This is part of his details: <player>
<fideid>405230</fideid>
<name>Raoof, Adam N</name>
<country>ENG</country>
<sex>M</sex>
<title></title>
<w_title></w_title>
<o_title>IA,IO</o_title>
<foa_title></foa_title>
<rating>2131</rating>

Comment: @BrianTowers, Andrew /  Thank you for pointing this out. I deleted this column originally when I imported it and didn't think it was that significant (column was essentially empty when I did so, and forgot about it) The arbiter/other title information will be useful for the barplot, map and globe

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the googleMotion chart above now

Comment: I have now posted a screenshot of the time series chart of chess ratings. The example is Gelfand's standard rating for the past decade. He's a crazy guy, gaining rating points as he got older. This time series chart isn't complete as I would like to add additional players on the chart eventually, and get more data. Right now, I only have data for January for every year.

Comment: I have completed the time series chart, the prototype of a 3d graph, and redesigned the app completely, it looks 10X better imo, more professional